# Is there any way to get list of groups domain user is part of using ansible modules without using win_shell module

Tags: windows, module, ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to delete the domain user from local groups but unable to find the domain user is part of which local group currently I'm using

```yaml
- name: Add a local and domain user to a local group
  win_group_membership:
    name: administrators
    members:
      - testldn2-1
           #- DOMAIN\TestUser
    state: absent
```

but this works for individual group

Comment: This is a requirement not a question. SO is a place to ask questions and provide answers about programming related issues, not a developer marketplace. Please edit your question, adding at the very least what you have already done, to make your question [on-topic](/help/on-topic). Before you start editing you will want to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- name: remove domain user from groups list
  win_domain_user:
    name: <user>
    state: present
    groups:
      - Power Users # group names here
      - Remote Destop Users 
    groups_action: remove
```

Find the [Documentation Here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_domain_user_module.html)

Comment: this module works only with AD where as i want to query local groups for user who can be  AD account or domain account or local user so hat i will get info about user is part of which groups and then will delete .

Comment: You have to use a custom powershell script for your requirement.